# List all folders under Jenkins with their path

Tags: api, jenkins

Suppose a have a folder named `TOPLEVEL`, which contains many jobs inside. I want to be able list all the **folders** that `TOPLEVEL` contains.

I have tried accessing the following `json` tree url, but it does not seem to work.

`http://jenkins/job/TOPLEVEL//api/json?tree=jobs[name,_class=%22hudson.model.Folder%22]&wrapper=root`

It is still giving me stuff like:

```
{
"_class": "hudson.model.FreeStyleProject",
"name": "testProject1"
}
```

Nevertheless, it does give me folders, but it also gives me other types of jobs, which I do not want?

```
{
"_class": "com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.Folder",
"name": "Github"
}
```

when I do not require this. Am I doing my API call wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this
https://gist.github.com/justlaputa/5634984

#### jobs

`jenkins_url` + `/api/json?tree=jobs[name,color]`

#### builds

`jenkins_url` + `/job/${job_name}/api/json?tree=builds[number,status,timestamp,id,result]`

#### last build

- all build info:

`jenkins_url` + `/job/${job_name}/lastBuild/api/json`

- build progress:

`jenkins_url` + `/job/${job_name}/lastBuild/api/json?tree=result,timestamp,estimatedDuration`

timestamp = start time

estimatedDuration = duration